# methods for element width/height

Tags: javascript, css

**Question:** Is there a scenario where `getBoundingClientRect` and `window.getComputedStyle` would differ in `width` or `height`?

I just found a inconsistent `width` (see under) in IE when a element has `box-sizing` where `window.getComputedStyle` returns the wrong value.

So I thought about overriding just `width` and `height` with values from `getBoundingClientRect` but not sure if there are cases where that would fail.

Example of the problem (broken in IE): http://jsfiddle.net/bwPM8/

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box');
var gBCR_width = box.getBoundingClientRect().width; // always 200
var wGCS = window.getComputedStyle(box).width; // 200 some browsers, 160 in IE
```

Comment: I havent looked at IE for a long time but IE in `getComputedStyle` seems to calculate padding and border inside the box while other browsers calculate it outside. `200px - (10+10 border) - (10+10 padding) = 160px`

Comment: @erosman, thanks for feedback. Yes, IE calculates in its own way. Do you know the answer to the question I wrote in the first line?

Comment: Sorry, I dont (not exactly) but ... `getComputedStyle()` get its data from CSS so the data is hard-coded in the CSS. `getBoundingClientRect()` is a text rectangle object that encloses a group of text rectangles. In other words, it seems that its gets its data from the rendering of the object. The difference, comes from the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) and as it says in that page: _"IE8 and earlier versions of IE, included padding and border in the width property. To fix this problem, add a <!DOCTYPE html> to the HTML page."_

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are several differences between these two functions.

`getBoundingClientRect()` will return a text rectangle object that encloses a group of text rectangles (the union of the rectangles returned by `getClientRects()` for the element, i.e., the CSS border-boxes associated with the element). The latter, `getComputedStyle()`, will return the computed CSS style of that element, after applying all CSS.

Therefore the resulting width and height can be drastically different.

For instance, by simply applying a `transform` to that element you already change the width that is returned by `getBoundingClientRect()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/epW3c/

Moreover, even if you add a border or padding to your element, the width and height will be different in both cases.

Depending on the version of IE you're testing this on, you might be experiencing the infamous [Internet Explorer box model bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug) which causes the interpretation of the dimensions of the element to be wrong. Make sure you're not running your page in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) by adding the doctype properly.

Answer (score 5):

In IE the CSS `padding: 10px;` cause overflow and that gives you extra size of the computedStyle..

Also IE calculates `Borders` separately from the object.

This sums up the answer with difference of `40px`

Now with `overflow:hidden;` OR `box-sizing: border-box;` that cause value go in minus so will become 200px - 40px = 160px.

*Note:* Here if we remove `overflow:hidden` will not make any difference as the `box-sizing:border-box` cause the design not to grow further from defined height and width.

I have generate another [`fiddle 1`](http://jsfiddle.net/bwPM8/3/) (without padding) which gives

'computedValue : 180px'

And with `Border:0px` the [`fiddle 2`](http://jsfiddle.net/bwPM8/4/) give results
same as in other browser..

I hope this clears what causes what in IE(IE has its own mind that sometimes cause pain to developers)